# Rotating Banner Module Shrinks Banner Image When It Should Not

Tags: 7, theming, media

I am using drupal 7.23,
and the module Rotating Banner https://drupal.org/project/rotating_banner
I have the banner size set to " The banner will shrink to fit the page. "
Unfortunately it is shrinking the banner when there is no change in page size.

All I have to do is load the page. The banner is initially fully expanded to the max size of the screen, but as it rotates, it will change to have a very small width.
This appears to be random, in that it just happens with enough image rotations.

Here is the css for the regular image before it becomes travel size

[image]

Here is the css for the image after it smalls down

[image]

It appears that the internal code for the module thinks the screen size shrunk down big time, but I don't know why....
I would appreciate anyones advice on this matter....

Thanks so much,

david

Answer (score 0):

I think the module is a bit buggy.
I changed it to not have the dynamic size setting, but went with static
but just didn't put in a height/width.
Since I am using bootstrap with drupal I surrounded the image with a

...

Which then forces the image to dynamically respond properly.
So, a hack.